# I have two textboxes first Textbox is placed in 1 row of 1 column and other in 45th row of 1st column in asp.net table?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I want if checkbox1 is checked then textbox45 will be visible and textbox1 will be disabled..

but i want textbox45 will take place of textbox1.

again if i check checkbox1 and checkbox 2 then textbox1 and textbox 2 will be visible in 1 and second row of the asp.net table ... how to do this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have checkbox controls like this -

```
<asp:CheckBox id="checkbox1" runat="server"
                    AutoPostBack="True"
                    Text="checkbox1"                    
                    OnCheckedChanged="Check1_Clicked"/>
```

Then, you can create textbox controls like this but then

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtbox1"
                    visible="false"
                    runat="server"/>
```

And on the Check1_Clicked event -

```
void Check1_Clicked(Object sender, EventArgs e) 
{    
    txtbox1.Visible = False;
    txtbox45.Visible = True;

    //After controlling the visiblity, you can dynamically position your textbox on your form.
    txtbox45.Style("Position") = "Absolute"
    txtbox45.Style("Top") = "50px"
    txtbox45.Style("Left") = "100px"  
    // provide suitable values to position the textbox accordingly for all your textboxes

}
```